# How to source a part of a file

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode, register

I can source a file, e.g. my `vimrc` with `:so %` or `:so <filename>`. But what do I do when I need to source only part of a file. I want some way to visually select a portion of the file with `:h v` and then source it. Kinda like emacs's `M-x eval-region`

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases, but `:@*`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you've done your Visual selection run this:

```
y:@"<CR>
```

`y` copies the selection to the unnamed register (`"`) since we didn't explicitly name a register. Then `:@"` executes the contents of that register as Ex commands.

See `help :@` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262519/vim-how-to-source-a-part-of-the-buffer

Comment: So, you're saying I should just copy and paste it in my command-line window? That's... easier than I thought.

Comment: You're not pasting to the command line, which would entail something like reading the data and storing it in an input buffer. You're just telling vim to process the data from an existing memory allocation (the register store) which is a lot less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative implementation which does not stop at the first error in a script:

```
command! -range=% Exec call execute(getline(<line1>, <line2>), '')
```

Now in visual mode type `:'<,'>Exec` to process the selected lines (`'<,'>` is added automatically as usual). Also, `:Exec` in normal mode executes the whole buffer, just as `:source %`, except the buffer does not need to be saved first.

If needed the mappings, they can be added easily.